# What is the the projection of vector b onto the matrix A if b is in the Column space of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is  the the projection of vector b onto the matrix A if b is in the Column space of A? This is a strange question for me. Can you do a projection in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

$b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

So, if you project onto the columns of $A$, you recover $b$.